# Fluxx - Monty Python: Finger of God & Play All

Tags: fluxx

I've just encountered a situation playing this with my daughter where she has played the Finger of God and there's a Play All card in the table. Does this mean she can keep Playing Finger of God until there are no more Creepers on the table? Seems to be a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the wording of the card, and a strict interpretation of the rules, **yes**.

To be more specific, if the rule "Play All" is in effect and your daughter has played the "Finger of God", she *may* choose to smite a Creeper in play and, in doing so return the FoG to her hand, where she *must*, at some point in her turn, play it again.

At which point, she can again choose to smite a Creeper, and so on until either there are no Creepers left, or she chooses to not use the FoG's ability, *or* for some reason she is not able to play the card again (e.g. the rules change back to "Play 1", or she trades her hand with the FoG in it).